# Bluetooth doesn't work in Fedora 15 when system wakes up or changes runlevel

Tags: bluetooth, runlevel, fedora-15, systemd

I'm experiencing weird problem when using Bluetooth on Fedora 15. First, to get Bluetooth working, I had to follow [this post](http://kdekorte.blogspot.com/2011/04/fedora-15-bluetooth.html).

Now, when I boot up and login (runlevel 5, GNOME 3), `systemctl status bluetooth.service` results in:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth Manager
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service)
      Active: active (running) since Wed, 08 Jun 2011 08:34:17 +0200; 56s ago
    Main PID: 893 (bluetoothd)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/bluetooth.service
          ├  893 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n
          ├ 1989 [khidpd_045e0700]
          └ 2000 [khidpd_045e0762]
```

So everything's fine.

However, when I change runlevel or tell system to sleep, Bluetooth stops working. `systemctl status bluetooth.service` results in:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth Manager
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service)
      Active: inactive (dead) since Wed, 08 Jun 2011 08:37:57 +0200; 40s ago
     Process: 860 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/bluetooth.service
```

And I have to restart it (`systemctl restart bluetooth.service`) to get it working again. This is inconvenient, as my main keyboard is a Bluetooth one.

Everything worked fine on Fedora 14.

So, how can I make it work without having to restart Bluetooth service every time I change runlevel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the Bluetooth service to automatically restart on exit.  To do so, first copy the `bluetooth.service` file from `/lib/systemd/system/` to `/etc/systemd/system/`.  Then, add the following line to the `[Service]` section of the newly copied file:

```
Restart=always
```

Finally, alert `systemd` that its configuration has been changed by running this command (as `root`):

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now, whenever the Bluetooth daemon exits, as it's doing when your system sleeps, `systemd` will automatically restart it.

Comment: I've tried that before. Daemon is still active after waking PC up, but my devices can't connect.

Comment: @Dr McKay:  In that case, it's probably a bug.  I suggest that you [report it](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora).  File it in the `bluez` package.  They'll send it along to the `systemd` or `udev` folks if that's where the problem is.